# Pass "content of file" instead of "location of file"

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line-interface

I am creating an electron app for windows and using some windows app dependencies.
The other dependencies require a file path as variable. Example

```
dependency.exe --config /path/to/config/file.conf
```

i wish to replace /path/to/config/file.conf directly with the content

for example

```
dependency.exe --config $("configuration content")
```

Reason? I do not wish to create a config file for user to see and keep it as closed source

Comment: what is `dependency.exe` ?

Comment: there are many. one of them is openvpn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `dependency.exe` is your app. You can have it read from standard input, then use the `type` command to get the configuration file contents:

```
type file.conf | dependency.exe
```

Comment: Where is the content? I need to store the file anyway?